# BeautifulSoup won't consider linebreaks while parsing a table

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse a table using BS and ultimately put some if its content into a dataframe. For tables there is only one line of text in each row this works fine.
There are however cases where some tables cells contain multiple lines of text. One of those examples looks like this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPJTT.jpg)
Note: I highlighted the table so you get an idea of how it is structured.

Unfortunately, parsing those using BS and converting them into a df using `df = pd.read_html(str(CompTab))` result in a mess since the line breaks are not considered as you can see here:
[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Pcy.jpg)

Here you can see one of the cells in the "Fiscal Years" column with its html code:
[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxlPe.jpg)

After running:

```
resp = requests.get(url_to_use, headers=headers)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
    tables = soup.find_all("table")
    #Select the correct table
    for table in tables:
            if ('Name' in str(table)) and ('Year' in str(table)) and ('Salary' in str(table)):
                CompTab = table
    print(CompTab.prettify())
```

...and searching the html code for the "Fiscal Years" column it seems that while BS doesn't ignore the 
 html tags but convert them to `<br/>` tags:

```
#Partial Output of print(CompTab.prettify())
<td valign="top">
   <font face="Times New Roman" size="2">
    2006
    <br/>
    2005
    <br/>
    2004
   </font>
  </td>
```

I tried using the lxml parser instead and even replaced the `<br/>` tags by `<br>`. Both had no effect.
How do I manage to get an output that considers the line breaks as they occur in the original table?

Comment: the original table is malformed, beautifulsoup has no blame here. one way or another you'll have to reshape it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table maybe buried somewhere in https://www.sec.gov/os/accessing-edgar-data.  Anyhow...

[image]

So...

**Maybe:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001000230/000119312507035211/ddef14a.htm'

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
tables = pd.read_html(page.text.replace('<BR>','\n'))

df = pd.DataFrame(tables[50])

# df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.iloc[1],df.iloc[2]])
# line above or the line below - pick one, comment the other out
df.columns = df.iloc[2]

df = df.iloc[3:]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.dropna(axis=1)

df = df.loc[:,~(df=='$').any()]

display(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Exporting:**

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame
StyleFrame(df).to_excel('out.xlsx').save()
```

[image]

Seems that those squares are some `\x97` chars in there you can obviously remove when cleaning it up.